# Return Column with list of Keywords present in String Column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list keywords and a dataframe:

`keywords=['chair','table', 'fan']`

```
Description

The table is 6 inches long
The fan is really good
The table fan is cheap
The chair is broken
The chair is on the table
```

I want to search the list of keywords and create a new column with which keyword from the list is present in the `Description` column.

```
Description                   Keyword

The table is 6 inches long    table
The fan is really good        fan
The table fan is cheap        table, fan
The chair is broken           chair
The chair is on the table     chair, table
```

I have searched for a few solutions, but none of them seems to work. I tried the following code on my own:

```
for i in word_set:
    for x in range(0, len(df)):
        if(df['Event Message'][x] in (i)):
            df['word'] = i
```

But obviously the time complexity is too high and is taking lot of time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and join values in list by regex or - `|`:

```
keywords=['chair','table', 'fan']
df['Keyword'] = df['Description'].str.findall('|'.join(keywords)).apply(set).str.join(', ')

print (df)
                  Description       Keyword
0  The table is 6 inches long         table
1      The fan is really good           fan
2      The table fan is cheap    table, fan
3         The chair is broken         chair
4   The chair is on the table  chair, table
```

If need words boundaries for avoid extract subtrings:

```
keywords=['chair','tab', 'fan']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in keywords)

df['Keyword1'] = df['Description'].str.findall(pat).apply(set).str.join(', ')
df['Keyword2'] = df['Description'].str.findall('|'.join(keywords)).apply(set).str.join(', ')
print (df)
                  Description Keyword1    Keyword2
0  The table is 6 inches long                  tab
1      The fan is really good      fan         fan
2      The table fan is cheap      fan    tab, fan
3         The chair is broken    chair       chair
4   The chair is on the table    chair  chair, tab
```

EDIT: For improve performance is possible use custom function with split and test membership in set:

```
keywords=['chair','table', 'fan']
s = set(keywords)
f = lambda x: ', '.join(set([y for y in x.split() if y in s]))
df['Keyword1'] = df['Description'].apply(f)
```

Also list comprehension should be faster:

```
df['Keyword1'] = [', '.join(set([y for y in x.split() if y in s])) for x in df['Description']]

print (df)
                  Description      Keyword1
0  The table is 6 inches long         table
1      The fan is really good           fan
2      The table fan is cheap    fan, table
3         The chair is broken         chair
4   The chair is on the table  table, chair
```

Thank you, @Henry Yik for another solution with `set.intersection`:

```
df['Keyword1'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split()).intersection(s)))
```

Comment: hi, this works, but the time taken to execute is pretty high and also like there are repetitions happening, any way to fix these? Like same keyword if it is happening 4 times in the sentence, it is coming up 4 times

Comment: @DebadriDutta - For first solutions is added `apply(set)`, also added new 2 solutions, can you check it?

Comment: You can also use set intersection like `lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split()).intersection(s))`.

Comment: @jezrael there is one problem that I found out right now, is that if the plural form is being used, lets say `chairs` or `tables` then they are not getting captured.

Comment: @DebadriDutta - can you check `df['Keyword1'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set([y for y in s if y in x])))` ? But then performance is worse

Comment: @DebadriDutta - or add `s` to end of values of list - hack, because some plural are different generally `s = set(keywords + [x +'s' for x in keywords])
print (s)
{'table', 'chair', 'chairs', 'tables', 'fans', 'fan'}`